# CentOS 7 ifup scripts actually doesn't change interface name

Tags: centos, linux-networking

It has occurred to me that in CentOS7. While one can still specify interface names in sysconfig, the ifup scripts actually does not change interface fact "via ip link set dev ${DEVICE} name".

For example, if I were to specify the following ifcfg-eth0

```
DEVICE=eth0
NAME=F0
```

And then type "ifup eth0", interface won't be renamed.

Has anyone else observed this? Has this always been the case?